# Running React Native projects present at github on android devices

Tags: android, react-native

**Background:**

I followed [this](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/tutorial.html) tutorial and successfully ran this on my device and now I am trying to run other react native projects present on github, but have not been successful so far.

**Problem Statement:**

I want to run [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/Examples/Movies) project on my android device.

There are clear instructions for running this on emulator but I can not seem to figure out how to run this on an android device.

**Edit:**

I have already followed the instructions and successfully ran a sample application. Now to run the project in an emulator these steps should be followed:

```
. cd react-native
./gradlew :Examples:Movies:android:app:installDebug
./packager/packager.sh
```

Now I am looking for the steps to run this example directly on a device.

Answer (score 1):

This should be rather straightforward. The idea is to run on your USB debugging-enabled device while making sure the React server is reachable by running adb reverse:

> adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081

Again, this requires your device to be hooked up to your development machine though there is also an option to hook up to local dev server via WiFi. More on this [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device-android.html).

Comment: Updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

Instructions on doing this are here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device-android.html

This method works on android version supported by react-native:

> 1. Make sure your laptop and your phone are on the same Wi-Fi network.
> 2. Open your React Native app on your device. You can do this the same way you'd open any other app.
> 3. You'll see a red screen with an error. This is OK. The following steps will fix that.
> 4. Open the Developer menu by shaking the device or running adb shell input keyevent 82 from the command line.
> 5. Go to Dev Settings.
> 6. Go to Debug server host for device.
> 7. Type in your machine's IP address and the port of the local dev server (e.g. 10.0.1.1:8081). On Mac, you can find the IP address in System Preferences / Network. On Windows, open the command prompt and type ipconfig to find your machine's IP address (more info).
> 8. Go back to the Developer menu and select Reload JS.

Comment: Updated my Question.

Answer (score 1):

- Try disconnection your emulator and connect your device.
- Make sure you have the right adb-drivers installed.
- rerun `./gradlew :Examples:Movies:android:app:installDebug`
- open the app on the device

Then follow the steps provided by [kamikazeOvrld](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35237258/4797532).

Comment: Sample code runs successfully on my device. Do I still need any other adb-driver?  Running `./gradlew :Examples:Movies:android:app:installDebug` gives the following error: ndk-build binary cannot be found, check if you've set $ANDROID_NDK environment variable correctly or if ndk.dir is setup in local.properties