# Running React Native Android on device

Tags: react-native

I followed this [official help page](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device-android.html) and also consulted this [previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35147204/running-react-native-projects-present-at-github-on-android-devices).

But I still don't know what is wrong here.

[image]

Let's take step by step:

1. **Ensure the package server is running.** From the screenshot, you can see the command I typed "react-native run-android" and the reponse "Starting JS server..."
2. **Ensure your device is connected...** Yes, Vysor sees my device.  Wee see Vysor showing the app running in the screenshot.
3. ...**USB enabled** Yes, the app is running, that's why we see the red error screen, but it's the app running nevertheless.
4. **Run "adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081"** Yes, the screenshot shows that I ran the command.
5. **Device and port...** Yes, did that too.  See next screenshot

[image]

What am I still doing wrong?  How can I make it work?

Comment: Is the device shown if you run `adb devices`? Also, note that `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081` only works for Android versions 5.0 and up.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- Run `npm run start` in one console window to start the react-native development server.
- Then open a separate console window to run `react-native run-android`.

I sometimes ran into problems if I don't start the development server in a separate console window.

Further notes:

- Make sure that your device is shown if you run `$ adb devices` in your console.
- Note that `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081` only works for Android versions 5.0 and up.

Comment: what to do for versions below 5.0, I got 4.2.2 s4 mini

Answer (score 4):

Could you provide us the screenshot of React Packager - run 'npm start' before doing 'react-native run-android'.

I am using Visual Studio Code with React Native tools extension that takes care of port forwarding, deploying the app to device/emulator and it works okay - I get similar screen at start, but clicking 'Reload' takes care of it.

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck at this exact step and finally I checked my firewall and lo and behold it was blocking the connection from my device to my computer. I unblocked it and after a reload everything worked.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I would provide some context to your answer. Maybe some steps on the OS/Firewall you are using and screengrabs, which would help people in similiar circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
react-native start --reset-cache
react-native run-android
```