# React Native App on Android FireTV device

Tags: android, facebook, react-native, amazon-fire-tv

I am trying to run my app on Android device: AmazonFireTV.

TAB1:
-> Created the app using 
    **react-native init FireTVDemo**
-> Run the app after npm start on other tab
    **react-native run-android**.

Installed on 1 device.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 14.295 secs

This build could be faster, please consider using the Gradle Daemon: https://docs.gradle.org/2.14.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Running /Users/xxxxx/Library/Android/sdk//platform-tools/adb -s 68.128.177.159:5555 reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
***error: more than one device and emulator
Could not run adb reverse: Command failed: /Users/xxxxx/Library/Android/sdk//platform-tools/adb -s 68.128.177.159:5555 reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081***
Starting the app on 68.128.177.159:5555 (/Users/xxxxx/Library/Android/sdk//platform-tools/adb -s 68.128.177.159:5555 shell am start -n com.firetvdemo/.MainActivity)...
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.firetvdemo/.MainActivity }
shell:FireTVDemo xxxxxx$ hsitory
-bash: hsitory: command not found

---

TAB2:

shell:FireTVDemo xxxxxx$ **npm run start**

---

> FireTVDemo@0.0.1 start /Users/xxxxx/reactn/FireTVDemo
>   node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start

Scanning 555 folders for symlinks in /Users/xxxxx/reactn/FireTVDemo/node_modules (3ms)
 │  Running packager on port 8081.                                            │ 
 │                                                                            │ 
 │  Keep this packager running while developing on any JS projects. Feel      │ 
 │  free to close this tab and run your own packager instance if you          │ 
 │  prefer.                                                                   │ 
 │                                                                            │ 
 │  https://github.com/facebook/react-native                                  │ 
 │                                                                            │ 
Looking for JS files in
   /Users/v826538/reactn/FireTVDemo

React packager ready.

### Loading dependency graph, done.

**error: more than one device and emulator Could not run adb reverse: Command failed: I am getting this error**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Able to resolve this issue. It was due to my restricted network. Once I use my local router connected to device and PC (Build system / Android Studio) it worked fine. In short following the steps mentioned in below link will make it work for android device. (with version API21 or above (Android 5* or above)). If its still not working check your network.

[Running React Native Android on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38410756/running-react-native-android-on-device?rq=1)